What does colon(:) do in Python dictionaries?
I stumbled upon this code while debugging something. Is the second line a valid Python code? I tried running this and it ran successfully without any errors. Shouldn't I be getting a syntax error since = is used for assigning values in dictionaries?
dict1 = {'temp':10}
dict1['temp'] : 5


you are using, in a very non-sense way, type annotation

You could find the walrus operator := also

What you're seeing is the type annotation syntax. In your case it does absolutely nothing but is not invalid.

Annotations must be valid expressions that evaluate without raising exceptions at the time the function is defined (but see below for forward references).

